# Create Jar File from Swing Application using Mail API

Tags: java, jar, jakarta-mail, executable-jar

I am having trouble making my application into a .jar file. I have tried

```
jar cfve file.jar Main *.class
```

Where Main is the entry point, and *.class is all the class files (I have about 4 inner classes, so it made plenty of .class files). Now this application uses the Java Mail API. When I downloaded javamail-1.4.6, I had no idea where to put it. Users tell me, "put it in your classpath", but I have no idea what that means in terms of folders on my computer. I have tried to concatenate the folders path to the end of my path environment variable, but I'm not sure if that worked or not.

Getting back to the jar file, when I click on the created .jar file, nothing happens. No frames open, or anything. Can anyone help me out with this, and perhaps explain what it is I'll need to do to permanently add the mail API? Thanks

Best...SL

Comment: Due to the (relative) complexity of running executable JAR's with bundled dependencies, I would recommend using tools like [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) or [Eclipse FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using some IDE e.g Eclipse/NetBeans to build your application, you simply have to put the jar in your project (usually in lib folder) and add it to the build path.
Then when you create an executable jar file your external jar files should be included in it.

You can manually add the jar file to the class path in the manifest file itself.
example -

```
Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
```

By using the Class-Path header in the manifest, you can avoid having to specify a long -classpath flag when invoking Java to run the your application.

One more thing, since you said "when I click on the created .jar file, nothing happens" you can run your jar file from command prompt to see any errors if the jar file fails to execute and load the classes from jar files if it is not included in your class path.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Not using an IDE. When I run the created jar file I get a NoClassDefFoundError for javax/mail/Authenticator. This leads me to believe the API was not properly included in the jar yes?

Comment: Normally the JavaMail jar file will not be included in your application jar file (but search for "onejar" if you think you really want to do that).  Instead, your application jar file will be packaged in a zip file or some other installer bundle, along with the JavaMail jar file.  When you install your application, your jar file and the JavaMail jar file will be stored on the local disk, and your jar file will use the Class-Path technique above to reference the JavaMail jar file.  Then you can run your application using "java -jar myapp.jar", or double click it.